# Returning element from a structure array

Tags: c

I need to return one element from a structure array. I get errors, so I would like to know how to do that:

```
-(struct Point3D)getMyColor
{
    struct Point3D
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    };
 struct Point3D points[15] =
    {
        {204, 74, 110},
        {118, 56, 198},
        {175, 122, 231}, // I WANT TO RETURN THIS ONE TO THE CALLER
        {3, 197, 47},
        ....

    }

 return  WHAT?    // (points[4] give error)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is C code? Not Objective-C?

Comment: You sould post the code which you are looking help for. As you said the `points[2]` is actually `points[19]` in comment to @Palec 's answer, how can someone help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you define the structure inside the function, which means that it's not possible to use it from outside it.

First move the structure definition to somewhere where the caller can use it, then follow the advice of other answers.

---

By the way, you have *undefined behavior* in you code as well. You declare the array `points` to contain *two* structures but initializes it with *four*, thereby overwriting the space allocated by the compiler for the array.

Comment: but i do wants it to be private.. there is no way to return 3 private values ? or i have to set a 3d array?

Comment: @Curnelious In that case I suggest you pass in an array as an argument to the function, and then fill in that array with the proper values. You simply can not use the structure outside the function, even as a return type. How would the caller be able to know what it is otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

you should return the third element, which is `points[2]` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
return points[4];
```

gives you an error, because you are trying to access the item on index 4 while your items have indices 0, 1, 2 and 3. So you want to

```
return points[2];
```

Comment: this is actually false.  i wrote 4 just for demonstration, the array has 19 values and i tried to go to 5. so its defiantly not the problem

Comment: @Curnelious Puzzled by bad demonstration. Joachim Pileborg spotted the main problem correctly.